# Expo `Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync()` always return status denied

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I’ve built a React native Expo internal android application in the apk format. I’ve setup the app and firebase for push notification correctly.

But when I install the apk on an Android phone I always get status = `denied` when I call:

```
const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
```

It is like if the application has by default push notification declied. But then if I manually enable notification for my application in the android preferences, then all push notification is working well.

So I think my setup is correct but I don’t understand why I cannot ask to enable notification from my app with the `Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync` method. Is it a normal behaviour for apk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Android 13 the prompt asking to grant the permission will not appear until at least one notification channel is created.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#permissions

Comment: Thanks a lot @Freddy, it is working well. Documentation was not up-to-date when I implemented it. But now it is OK and it works well.

Comment: So in terms of the setup code https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/ where do we call [setNotificationChannelAsync()](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#setnotificationchannelasyncidentifier-string-channel-notificationchannelinput-promisenotificationchannel--null) exactly? And I'm not sure what a "channel identifier" is as the first argument.

Comment: ok the docs seem to have been updated with calling `Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync`, but the prompt to allow notifications from Android doesn't come up. Doing a call to `Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();` fails every time. With

```
Object {
  "android": Object {
    "importance": 0,
    "interruptionFilter": 1,
  },
  "canAskAgain": false,
  "expires": "never",
  "granted": false,
  "status": "denied",
}
```

I have to manually go into the permissions for the app to grant permissions for notifications to be able to get an expo token.
What am I missing?

Comment: @magician11 for me the prompt after registering channel shows but the token doesn't show up, also there isn't any error..., it's only on android 13... Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76127440/4754175 this might help

Comment: i am also missing the system alert, no matter what i try. this somehow changes with an Expo SDK upgrade, because it wasn't a problem before. in addition, it is not related to Android 13 only, older versions behave the same. any ideas?
the notification channel is awaited and created before any Notifications. access.